# -le comparison problem in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm under Ubuntu 11.10, when I execute this program in bash I have the following error:

```
exec.bash: line 25: [: 0.1: integer expected as an expression
```

line 25 is:

```
while [ $p -le 1.0 ]
```

in the following context

```
p=0.1

while [ $p -le 1.0 ]
do
    echo ----probability---- $p
    java $jvmargs -classpath $CP jbenchmarker.MainSimulation $p
    (( p= $p + 0.1 ))
done
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Your `while` loop can be replaced by a for-loop. Since Bash cannot handle floating point arithmetic, you should use normal integers instead and use a program like `bc` for creating floats. The `scale=1;` command before `$i/10` ensures that there is always a single decimal (e.g. 0.1).

```
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++))
do
    p=$(bc <<<"scale=1;$i/10")
    echo ----probability---- $p
    java $jvmargs -classpath $CP jbenchmarker.MainSimulation $p
done
```

This is equivalent to:

```
i=1
while ((i<=10))
do
    p=$(bc <<<"scale=1;$i/10")
    echo ----probability---- $p
    java $jvmargs -classpath $CP jbenchmarker.MainSimulation $p
    ((i++))
done
```

`command <<<...` is a neat trick that writes ... to the standard input of `command` and is equivalent to `echo ... | command`

Answer (score 2):

Bash does not do floating point arithmetics; only integer arithmetics. To compare or calculate with floats, you have to involve external commands, such as bc or awk. See [How can I calculate with floating point numbers instead of just integers?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022)